# Как возникло название град Павлов?

Tags: этимология, топонимика

В Книге Большого чертежу (16 век) упоминается град Павлов (на Оке), основанный, видимо, ещё ранее. Не могут ли уважаемые участники дать версию образования этого названия?

Есть предположение, что вторая часть происходит от ловища или лова, я первая от пав или пава, что, вроде бы, в то время могло означать лебедей или гусей-лебедей, т.е. крупную водоплавающую птицу; так что получается как бы "место ловли гусей-лебедей". В окрестности города и сейчас немало озёр и речек.

Жители города ранее назывались павловцы, с ударением на о; например знаменитый иконописец Никита Павловец; уничижительно же их именовали павлы бесхвостые, т.е. с опять же указанием на птиц.

Был бы очень признателен за любые высказанные на этот счёт мысли.

Comment: Дамы и господа, вроде бы есть интерес к вопросу, но почему так мало ответов?! Мыслей, идей? Могу вас заверить, вопрос не праздный, есть подозрение, что град Павлов возник на месте более древнего города, запустевшего к тому времени...

Answer (score 1):

Зачем же "мысли", когда есть учёными выверенная информация?

> История возникновения Павлово уходит в глубь веков и связана с
>   историей развития Российского государства. Самое раннее упоминание о
>   Павлове относится к началу второй половины XVI столетия. Первое
>   письменное упоминание о Павлове в грамоте Ивана Грозного датируется 5
>   апреля 1566 года. Это письменное упоминание условно считается годом
>   основания Павлова.
>
> Существует много легенд о происхождении названия города. Одна из них
>   говорит, что он получил своё название по имени некоего переселенца —
>   перевозчика Павла. Согласно другой, город был назван по имени первого
>   посадского в остроге, так как во всех важных документах упоминался как
>   Павлов Острог.

**Достопримечательности**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Вид с Троицкой горы на весенний разлив реки Оки. Затопленные луга.*

> В городе находится усадьба Гомулина, являющаяся объектом культурного
>   наследия регионального значения, соответствующее решение было принято
>   в 1983 году.
>
> Дом Е. Е. Алипова (ул. Нижегородская, 3). Построен в начале XIX века.
>   Сама улица неоднократно упоминается в «Павловских очерках» В. Г.
>   Короленко.
>
> Родина Павловской породы кур. Известностью пользуется культура
>   комнатного лимона, выведенного в Павлове.

**[источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)**

---

См. также:

**[Чем известен город Павлов-на-Оке?](http://morkof.ru/voprosy/3114-Chem-izvesten-gorod-Pavlov-na-Oke/)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> До похода Ивана Грозного на Казань в 1552 году на участке Оки от
>   Мурома до Нижнего Новгорода фактически проходила граница Московского
>   государства. Притязания царской администрации на расположенные южнее
>   этого рубежа территории оставались номинальными. Проживающее здесь
>   малочисленное мордовское население (с примесью черемисов - мещеры)
>   вряд ли признавало зависимость от кого бы то ни было. До нас дошли
>   немногие финно-угорские названия деревень и рек - Ока, Кудьма, Тарка,
>   Кишма, в которых коренные жители навсегда оставили свой след.
>
> Проникновение русского населения в этот край началось задолго до
>   Казанского похода. Первыми поселенцами были крестьяне из-под
>   Владимира, Ростова, Суздаля. Они бежали от постепенно усиливающегося
>   крепостного гнета. Их привлекало сюда наличие пригодных для пахоты
>   земель, изобилие дичи в лесах, богатые рыбой реки. А главное -
>   отсутствие феодальных владений, таивших в себе угрозу нового
>   закабаления. После похода Ивана Грозного на Казань поток беженцев
>   усилился. Местное население частично было оттеснено к югу, частично
>   ассимилировалось с пришельцами. На высоких берегах Оки, на лесных
>   полянах рубились избы, появились деревни. Постепенно расчищалась от
>   леса и распахивалась земля, налаживался привычный крестьянский быт.
>
> Время основания Павлова условно отнесено к 1566 году. Первое
>   письменное упоминание о нем мы находим в грамоте Ивана Грозного от 5
>   апреля 1566 года. Павлово было тогда дворцовым селом, т. е. входило в
>   состав царской вотчины, и доходы с него шли на содержание дворцового
>   хозяйства. В грамоте царь дает личное распоряжение приказчику Тимофею
>   Харлантьеву о передаче суздальскому Спас-Ефимьеву монастырю нескольких
>   озер, а также об уступке прав на ловлю рыбы крестьянам села Павлова в
>   многочисленных небольших озерах, расположенных в пойме Оки от впадения
>   в нее Кудьмы до устья Кусторки. Наиболее вероятная версия
>   возникновения этого документа такова. В 1565 году жертвой опричнины
>   сподвижник Ивана Грозного боярин А. Б. Горбатый-Шуйский. В его
>   обширную вотчину входили и земли, расположенные в окрестностях
>   современного г. Горбатова. Религиозный до фанатизма царь передал их
>   влиятельному в то время суздальскому Спас-Ефимьеву монастырю. Уточняя
>   границы нового владения, монахи затеяли тяжбу с павловским приказчиком
>   Тимофеем Харлантьевым из-за ничейных угодий, расположенных в пойме
>   Оки. Обе стороны обратились в Приказ Казанского дворца. Но решающее
>   слово в этом споре принадлежало царю, т. к. речь шла о дворцовой, т.
>   е. царской собственности. Приказчику было велено часть пойменных
>   земель с расположенными на них двумя озерами передать монастырю, в
>   остальной части навести порядок и прежде всего обеспечить поступление
>   в казну собираемого с нее денежного дохода. Из грамоты мы узнаем не о
>   временах основания Павлова, а о том, что оно уже существовало. Более
>   того - оно уже являлось административным центром небольшой округи, в
>   которую входили ближайшие деревни. Следовательно, принятый за
>   основание Павлова 1556 год - дата условная, на самом деле село
>   возникло раньше. С момента своего возникновения в связи со
>   своеобразным рельефом местности село Павлово существовало как два
>   почти самостоятельных поселения. Одно - на Спасской горе, рядом с
>   острогом, другое - в районе современного рынка, улиц Нижегородской,
>   Ленина, и некоторых других, вдоль речки Тарки.
>
> По нижегородским писцовым книгам 1588-1599 гг., стрелецкому сотнику из
>   села Павлов Острог Федору Родионову сыну Дуракову, по его челобитью в
>   Москву, было выделено в оклад в 1597 году поместье в Ивановском
>   полесье Сорочинской пустоши в Березопольском стане Нижегородцкого
>   уезда. Данное поместье было пожаловано Федору Родионовичу не случайно.
>   В конце 70-х - нач. 80-х годов XVI века по Нижегородцкому уезду
>   прокатилась волна черемисских набегов, названных с легкой руки
>   историков "черемисскими войнами". От черемисских набегов серьезно
>   пострадала Сосновская волость, д.Тумботино (по документам 1588-1600
>   гг. она названа пустошью). Павлов Острог и Павловская волость меньше
>   соседей пострадали от опустошительных набегов только благодаря
>   успешному военному руководству гарнизоном павловской крепости
>   стрелецким сотником, которым в это время, по косвенным документальным
>   источникам, являлся Федор Родионович. На смену состарившемуся на
>   царской службе бывалому воину в 1597-99 гг. был поставлен стрелецким
>   сотником в Павлов Острог Игнатий Ильин. Интересен в этом отношении и
>   такой факт: в первые десятилетия своего существования село имело два
>   названия - Павлов острог и Павлов перевоз. По приказу царя в середине
>   XVI века на крутом берегу Оки, в районе современной Спасской горы,
>   откуда хорошо просматривалась местность в южном и юго-восточном
>   направлениях, была срублена сторожевая крепость, ставшая местом
>   постоянного пребывания небольшой группы стрельцов. Городовые стрельцы
>   несли гарнизонную и пограничную службу, а также выполняли поручения
>   местной администрации. Они не платили налогов, не занимались
>   земледелием, но им разрешалось иметь кузницы и заниматься
>   рыболовством, охотой. Гарнизон крепости "Павлов острог" в XVI веке
>   состоял из 50 человек во главе со стрелецким сотником.
>
> Время было тревожное: несмотря на разгром Казанского и Астраханского
>   ханств, продолжала существовать угроза нападения на русские земли со
>   стороны крымских татар и степняков. Подобные крепости воздвигались
>   тогда вдоль всех границ Московского государства. Ну а второе название
>   - Павлов перевоз, откуда взялось оно?
>
> До сих пор продолжает бытовать легенда о некоем Павле, когда - то
>   соорудившем себе хижину на берегу Оки в районе современного рынка и
>   занимавшемся перевозом. Известно, что исторические легенды не
>   возникают на пустом месте, обычно они в художественной форме передают
>   имевшее место явление. Был Павел или нет - для нас не имеет значения.
>   Другое дело - заключенная в легенде идея о существовании в
>   незапамятные времена в районе рынка переправы через Оку. Если эту идею
>   принять, а не принять ее нет никаких оснований, мы должны согласиться,
>   что речь идет не просто о переправе. Ведь она дала название
>   населенному пункту. Значит, уже в далекие времена вокруг нее кипела
>   жизнь. За несколько десятилетий до возведения острога, возможно еще в
>   XV веке, Павлов перевоз мог быть перевалочным пунктом, через который
>   осуществлялись экономические связи русского населения, проживавшего по
>   течению Клязьмы, с мордовскими племенами. Такие связи могли
>   происходить постоянно или посезонно, с устройством торжищ и ярмарок. И
>   в том и в другом случае на переправе должны были возникнуть постоялый
>   двор, кузница, для ковки лошадей, дома людей, обслуживающих перевоз.
>   Здесь же могли находить пристанище те, чья профессия была связана с
>   рекой - рыбаки, лодочники, сплавщики леса. Все это, видимо имело место
>   задолго до возведения крепости. Только в этом случае название "Павлов
>   перевоз" могло настолько крепко запасть в сознание людей, что затем
>   около сотни лет конкурировало с другим названием - "Павлов острог".

**[источник](http://www.pavlovo.org/about/history/)**

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо за отклик, но в отношении названия города вы сами пишите, что это легенды, и уж поверьте мне, никакими учёными они не выверены.

Comment: А Вы, Евгений, полагаете, что на лингвистическом сайте есть кто-то из историков края или просто павловцев? Энтузиасты (нижний источник) что могли разобрали по косточкам...

Comment: речь идёт о формировании названия града - чисто лингвистическая проблема; пока история не при чём. Энтузиазм хорош, конечно, если он опирается на знания и здравый смысл.

Comment: Евгений, лингвистическая сторона — это как сформировать название из имени, а почему именное это имя выбрано — при чем тут лингвистика?

Comment: я и хочу понять, как возникло имя града, потому что имя Павел здесь, видимо, совершенно не при делах..

Comment: @Евгений, это к краеведам. Или к специалистам по топонимике, коих здесь не водится. ***Топони́мика (от др.-греч. τόπος «место» + ὄνομα «имя») — раздел ономастики, изучающий географические названия (топонимы), их происхождение, смысловое значение, развитие, современное состояние, написание и произношение.***

Comment: это к любому краю может относится - причём тут краеведы? Лингвистически такой путь образования возможен или нет? Вот в физике: закон сохранения энергии везде выполняется - и в Санта-Барбаре, и в Улан-Удэ.

Comment: Теперь понятно, о чем Вы. Тогда задайте вопрос в соответствующей формулировке: Возможно ли по законам лингвистики образовать топоним Павлов от корней пав и лов?

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, именно это мне и хотелось бы узнать и понять. Спасибо!

Comment: Так напишите об этом вверху, в самом вопросе, куда все смотрят.

Comment: А вроде бы там об этом и написано? Разве нет?

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос с такой формулировкой: ***Возможно ли по законам лингвистики образовать топоним Павлов от корней "пав" и "лов"?***

Comment: Спасибо, но я оставлю свой.

Comment: а картинки классные Прямо манят.

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Всеобщий географический и статистический словарь. Москва 1843.)

Поскольку первые упоминания о селе связываются по времени с передачей земель Спасо-Евфимиевскому монастырю, можно полагать, что строительство первых храмов, возведённых тогда, тоже соответствует этому периоду. Логично предположить, что один из них дал своё имя поселению.

Версия о сложном слове не реалистична, слишком обрывочны предполагаемые корни. Что до ударения, то оно может «гулять» согласно местным предпочтениям. Одно лишь возможно: если не *Павел*, то *Павло* лежит в основе топонима.

В словаре Ц-СЯ Дьяченко есть такая статья — о слове ***павлака***, но возмутительно краткая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из Википедии https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1591216 (см. где ударная! — shampar).

Па́влово (неофициально Па́влово-на-Оке́) — город районного значения в Нижегородской области России, административный центр Павловского района. Население 60,7 тыс. жителей.

Расположен на правом берегу р. Оки на Перемиловских горах, в 79 км от Нижнего Новгорода.

Comment: храмы: Никольский, Спасо-Преображенский, Троицкий, Воскресенский, Вознесенский, Иконы скорбящей Богоматери, часовни - м.б. что-то упустил, но Святого Павла точно не было. Тогда не бьётся как-то...

Comment: Кто знает, м. б. кто-то что-то упустил (разрушил), тогда бейся не бейся... М. б. до пяти каменных прежде (на тысячу-то дворов!) было с десяток церквей (скитов, пустошей) деревянных.

Comment: Нет, я немного в теме, церкви с именем Павла не было. Но вопрос вообще в другом - от ловища и пав могло сложится название град Павлов с ударением на о (жители - павлОвцы, а не пАвловцы)?

Comment: а почему не реалистична: Волок Ламский - Волоколамск; Угличе Поле - Углич. Вроде и реалистична...

Comment: Да потому, что итог такого слияния слов — Павлово. Короткое, страшно распространённое и понятное всем Павлово. Из сотни у 99 и вопроса с ударением не будет.

Comment: Но вы ошибаетесь - название было град Павлов (не Павлово, Павлов!!) и с ударением на последний слог. Могу дать ссылку на Книгу Большого чертежу (16 век) или другие источники.

Comment: Аргументируйте ссылкой на ударение и ссылкой, опровергающей статью из ВГС словаря, чтобы быть убедительным, а не убеждённым.

Comment: Вы знаете, статья из ВГС вообще ошибочна - село Павлово (а я говорил и говорю про град Павлов!) никогда не входило в Арзамасский уезд (Арзамас очень далеко), а находилось в Горбатовском уезде Нижегородской губернии. А вот река Тарка действительно существует, но с ней тоже всё непросто.

Comment: На карте 1867 г. — в границах Горбатовского (etomesto.ru/map-nn_1867-gorbatovskiy-uezd), а до составления словаря и ранее Павлово могло быть в иных, в том числе Арзамасского уезда, до его границы всего 40 вёрст.

Comment: Уважаемый shampar, я очень благодарен вам за участие в обсуждении и мне - извините за наглость - захотелось вас, как художника и дизайнера,  немного поощрить сведениями об одной из бывших достопримечательностей - а их немало - села Павлова: https://selshoz.ru/pticevodstvo/kury/pavlovskie